# Django login problems

Tags: python, django

I can register new user. But after logout, I cannot login again .It shows user does not exist. But when I checked admin panel I get hashed password.....

forms.py

```
 class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User Does Not Exist.")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password Does not Match.")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User is not Active.")

        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):  # users will login with their Email & Password
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        title = "Login"
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            # authenticates with Email & Password
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        context = {"form": form,
                   "title": title
                   }
        return render(request, "accounts/login.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ("GD", "Graphics & Design"),
        ("DM", "Digital & Marketing"),
        ("VA", "Video & Animation"),
        ("MA", "Music & Audio"),
        ("PT", "Programming & Tech")
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=6)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Purchase(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gig.title


class Review(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

I can register new user. But after logout, I cannot login again .It shows user does not exist. But when I checked admin panel I get hashed password.....

registration view.....

```
def register_view(request):  # Creates a New Account & login New users
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        title = "Register"
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            prof = Profile(user=user)
            prof.save()
            authenticate(email=user.email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")

        context = {"title": title, "form": form}

        return render(request, "accounts/form.html", context)


def logout_view(request):  # logs out the logged in users
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")
    else:
        logout(request)
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Do you have a custom user model? The built-in user model uses the username field to authenticate not the email field

Comment: yes I have a...

Comment: Can you add your custom user model and your registration view to the question?

Comment: yes,sir I added...pls checked

Comment: I think he was asking about user model not the profile so you should add the user model in your question

Comment: I  added model.py

Comment: any solutions?.